# Why don't (military-grade) parts provide g(acceleration) metrics?

Tags: physics

What is the maximum acceleration a device can handle which is capable of:

- GPS
- RF communication up to several of kilometers
- visible and/or IR cameras
- (basic) radar?

[This](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59577/is-it-possible-for-an-orion-drive-based-spaceship-to-experience-smooth-artificia) thread insists "over 1000g" is possible (though probably with not all the requirements I listed). A (competent) friend of mine insists a [МИГ 29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan_MiG-29) is submitted for repairs if over 9g were detected at any point.

This is not a practical question - I am simply curious. Thus scientific papers are preferred as answers. Experience too, of course.

---

As per @DKNguye 's comment. We are talking Solid State electronics. What is the maximum? Why is it no listed in datasheets? Even military-grade parts provide only temperature values.

---

Thanks for the comments, guys. I concur the question is not well formed ... but that's the best I can. And the comments answered it! Thanks again.

Comment: How is it in any way valid to treat an entire plane as if it were an electronic device? It obviously has a lot more in it than that There are no specially rated components to implementing a 20g or 40g  accelerometers on a board that I am aware of. I have not seen anything for 100gs either. I am pretty sure you can exceed 9gs just by shaking your hands. I would need to get my IMU to check.

Comment: Not an expert, so only commenting:  Probably because the individual components are not the weak point in a system.  The mounting and connections are.

Comment: Have you read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102564/designing-for-high-acceleration - Andy says "Over about 10,000 g we tend to solid pot the electronics and we've not had a problem with jobs shipped over many years up to g forces over 20,000."

Comment: I suspect the mig29 is scheduled for repairs after 9g continuous loads because the large mechanical parts of the airframe will have been stressed beyond its ratings, not because it’s semiconductors are failing. I think your study of acceleration would also do to distinguish between continuous loads and shock loads. Finally three of the examples you provide are radio based and will be affected by Doppler shift - civilian GPS is also programmed to halt output when the dynamics are too high to keep you from making missiles

Comment: Check out the M982, aka Excalibur made by GD and Raytheon.  It gets fired from a cannon, which is over 10k g. All those electronics survive the launch fine, just not the landing.